# accepting user inputs from the standard input where the amount of variable inputs could vary

Tags: c, scanf

I want to accept variables from the standard input but I dont want to define how many variables I am accepting so that the user could submit two or three variables.

for example I would have:

```
char key;
char name1[100];
char name2[100];


printf("Hello! insert your command:\n");
scanf("%c %s %s",&key, name1, name2);
```

but the user isnt required to insert a second name so that inputs "F John" and "L John Doe" "X" would all be accepted. Basically I don't want the input length to be predetermined I only need it to accept up 1 2 or 3 variables. Is scanf the proper way to do this or is there a better method?

currently it waits for all 3 variables to be assigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is scanf the proper way to do this or is there a better method?

Yes, `scanf` is entirely appropriate for this. However, you need to be aware that the spaces you've used in your format string *aren't*; they have a different meaning, as they match not just one single space but *any sequence zero or more whitespace characters* (including spaces, tabs, newlines). You'll want to use a `%*1[^ ]` directive, instead. You could define this as `#define SPACE_FORMAT "%*1[^ ]"` for clarity, and use it as follows:

```
int n = scanf("%c" SPACE_FORMAT "%s" SPACE_FORMAT "%s", &key, name1, name2);
```

Note carefully how I've stored the return value into `n`; if `scanf` successfully matches and assigns to:

- only the first object (pointed to by `&key`), it'll only return 1...
- the first (pointed to by `&key`) and second (pointed to by `name1`) object, it'll return 2...
- ... and so forth. If `scanf` fails due to some read error or reaching `EOF`, it'll return `EOF` (which is a negative integer), instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fgets()` to read the whole input string and then `sscanf()` from the string into the variables. `sscanf()` returns the number of successfully read fields. You can use this number to decide which variables have been initialized.

```
char buffer[100];
int n;
printf("Hello! insert your command:\n");
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
n = sscanf(buffer, "%c %s %s", &key, name1, name2);
# 1, 2 or 3
```

As it has been noted in a comment, the rest of the line will be read, too (up to `100-1=99` characters). I assume that there are no more fields of interest in the rest of the line.

Comment: Note that this does behave subtly different, as it'll read not just a character and two *words* (in the English lexical sense, tokens delimitered by whitespace), but also the tail of the line (up to 99 characters, at which point if this is desired, you'll want to discard beyond 99 characters up to the next `'\n'` anyway, so you'll need more code for that)... That might be desirable or undesirable, but regardless it is a subtle difference that typically goes unnoticed.

Comment: @Seb Correct. I assume that there is nothing else on the line, aside from up to three name components.